# Why was this question deleted and off topic?

Tags: discussion

https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/if-a-girl-is-underweight-and-looks-skinny-because-she-didnt-have-healthy-diet-u

Any way to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is off topic because it is not really about fitness, it is a general health question. That is something that needs to be discussed with a health professional. There really isn't a way to improve it and still ask the original question.

You could ask about gaining weight and muscle moving forward, however there are already several questions of that nature on the board and it could be closed as a duplicate.

As far as deleted, that is something that is automatically done by the system. The user Community is a system user that can clean up old and deleted posts.

Comment: Agreed. If the question is a standard how to gain weight and muscle, it's a duplicate. If the question is "can I reverse malnutrition for the first 23 years of my life" then I think that's off-topic.

Comment: Could it be asked on Biology stackexchange?

Comment: @vivek - Mmm... It *might* be on topic at medical science, but it would need to be carefully worded to not be personal. Personal medical advice is off topic pretty much everywhere, I really think this is something that should be discussed with a medical professional, as there may be unknown medical conditions relating to prolonged insufficient nutrition.

Comment: @JohnP okay then